# Problems with a for-loop statment that almost freezes my program

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, freeze

I have two for-statements that work, however, they go through so many cells that they end up freezing my excel for about 15 sec to half a min. I need help finding a way to run the code without freezing excel.

One of my codes does a formula if the statement is correct in the cell (running from row 5 down an unstated amount of rows). And my second code changes the `NumberFormat` to `"0,00"`, which is problamatic cause I have a lot of cells with numbers in them. It would probably be best to write the code in a different way than with a For-If statement, but I wasn't able to get it to work any other way than what I have below. I've tried adding an `DoEvents`, which changes nothing, the program still freezes.

First code which causes my program to run slow:

```
For x = 5 To Rows.Count
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(ws.Cells(x, 2)) = True Then
    ws.Cells(x, 14).FormulaR1C1 = "Formula 1"
    ws.Cells(x, 15).FormulaR1C1 = "Formula 2"
    ws.Cells(x, 16).FormulaR1C1 = "Formula 3"
    ws.Cells(x, 17).FormulaR1C1 = "Formula 4"
    ws.Cells(x, 18).FormulaR1C1 = "Formula 5"
ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(ws.Cells(x, 2)) = False Then
    Exit For
End If
Next x
```

Second code which causes my program to freeze for a few seconds before finishing:

```
For y = 2 To Columns.Count
For x = 5 To Rows.Count
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(ws.Cells(x, y)) = True Then
    ws.Cells(x, y).NumberFormat = "0.00"
    ws.Cells(x, y).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    ws.Cells(x, y).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Else
    Exit For
End If
Next x, y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all a "freeze" means in most cases that your code is still running (which can be a longer time than you expect).

The issue in your code is, that you run your loop through **all** rows/columns even if they are not used (empty).

```
For x = 5 To Rows.Count
```

Limit your loops to the actual amount of data. Find the last used row like

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last used row in column A
```

and use this in your loop

```
Dim iRow As Long
For iRow = 5 To LastRow
```

---

You can also find the last used column with the same method

```
Dim LastCol As Long
LastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last used column in row 1
```

and use this in your other loop

```
Dim iCol As Long
For iCol = 2 To LastCol
```

---

So you would end up with something like

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last used row in column A

Dim LastCol As Long
LastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last used column in row 1 

Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long
For iCol = 2 To LastCol 
    For iRow = 5 To LastRow
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(ws.Cells(iRow, iCol)) = True Then
            ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).NumberFormat = "0.00"
            ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next iRow
Next iCol
```

*Note that I gave your counter variables `x` and `y` more meaningful names so you always know which is the row counter and which the column counter.*

---

#### Alternative to your loop

Use the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells) to find all cells with numbers and format them **at once** wich should be amazingly faster.

```
Dim CellsWithNumbers As Range
Set CellsWithNumbers = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)

If Not CellsWithNumbers Is Nothing Then
    With CellsWithNumbers 
        .NumberFormat = "0.00"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
End With
```

If you want to find all formulas with a numeric result use `xlCellTypeFormulas` instead.

```
Dim CellsWithNumbers As Range
Set CellsWithNumbers = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)

If Not CellsWithNumbers Is Nothing Then
    With CellsWithNumbers 
        .NumberFormat = "0.00"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
End With
```

If you want constant and formula numbers use both one after the other.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is much appreciated. The alternative loop for the number format was very helpful and I also managed to get the first part of the code (with the formulas) to speed up by using your suggestion.